# How to stop Eclipse from accumulating Tomcat instances each time one is restarted?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm running Tomcat 8.5 in Eclipse 2019.3:

[image]

Every time I restart a Tomcat instance by clicking the green circle/triangle button, I end up with duplicate instances running:

[image]

How can I stop this from happening?

Here's some things I've already tried:

1. I tried upgrading to tomcat 9.0, it didn't help. This is the reason you see a couple of 9.0 configurations in a Stopped state.
2. I tried splitting up my application into two smaller apps, it didn't help. This is the reason you see two different Tomcat configurations of each version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a coding issue!  Once a Servlet Filter responsible for logging was removed, the problem went away. I presume that the Servlet Filter created a non-daemon thread that prevented termination of Tomcat, but I didn't dig deeper to confirm.